# Is it possible to migrate my Azure app service to a self hosted server via a docker image?

Tags: azure, docker, service, self, hosted

When I google this every result is a microsoft document describing how to bring code INTO Azure.  But I am looking for a way to take an existing Azure app service and make a docker image of it and then deploy that onto my own server.

Is this possible?

I believe Azure provides a mechanism to generate the docker image.  Is that all I need?

Comment: No, you'll need some way of running that image in some useful way.

Comment: No, you need to create a container and deploy your app in it